JavaScript Animations with Angular Universal Prerendering
I'm new to Angular (and Angular Universal) and need some information.
I'm particularly wondering how the JavaScript code of my Angular application is managed in the prerendered version.
I currently have an Angular application (version 15) that I want to prerender to serve with a classic Apache server. I notice that the JS code responsible for generating my page (fetching data from an API and rendering the frontend) executes correctly during the build of my site. However, the JS code that should generate various animations (such as an image carousel or menu collapse animations) does not execute when I open my files in the browser.
Is this normal behavior for Angular Universal? Or am I doing something wrong?
I've checked that all required scripts are included and there are no errors in the browser console. The animations work fine during development, but not with the prerendered files.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz or github repo where the issue happens!
